# What are the system requirements for an Aeon full node?

Tags: full-node, aeon, system-requirements

Recently I was trying to install an Aeon node on a VPS, but people said it hasn't yet implemented LMDB, so it needs a great deal of RAM to properly work, so my 2GB RAM VPS wouldn't be enough. How much RAM or other system requirements are needed to run a fully functional Aeon node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it isn't using LMDB yet, because I only have a 3.5 GB `blockchain.bin` file in the `~/.aeon` directory. I brew the software from HEAD, it says `aeon v0.9.6.0()`.

With regard to memory, as far as I can tell, on my macOS system, `aeond` is using about 9 GB of memory. I have no idea whether this would prevent the daemon from running on a system with only 2 GB.

**Update:**
I set up a Ubuntu (MATE) virtual machine and synchronized the Aeon blockchain using 6 GB of RAM. Reducing the amount of RAM ended up in the `aeond` daemon process getting killed. I am now running the VM without issues with 6 GB of RAM and solo-mining on 4 threads.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running it on a micro instance on AWS with 1 GB of RAM. I did sync with 8 GB, and then commented out the autosave of the blockchain and recompiled and moved to a micro instance and added a bunch swap, but I think it would have worked by just initially commenting out autosave and adding swap as well.

I think just comment out this line in cryptonote_core.cpp:
                 m_store_blockchain_interval.do_call(boost::bind(&blockchain_storage::store_blockchain, &m_blockchain_storage));